# Proper syntax for create view with a subquery?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, create-view

I want to Create a View using this code:

```
SELECT t1.FirstName, t1.LastName, t2.Sum FROM Customer as t1,(SELECT CustomerID,Sum(Total) as Sum  FROM Invoice GROUP BY(CustomerID)) as t2 WHERE t1.CustomerID=t2.CustomerID
```

The way that makes sense to me is to do

```
Create VIEW t2 as SELECT CustomerID,Sum(Total) as Sum  FROM Invoice GROUP BY(CustomerID)

Create VIEW CustomerInvoices as SELECT t1.FirstName, t1.LastName, t2.Sum FROM Customer as t1, t2  WHERE t1.CustomerID=t2.CustomerID
```

But that gives me a syntax error, so I'm not sure how to call the first view in the main view

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed, this syntax is not allowed in MySQL (although it is allowed in other databases):

```
SELECT t1.FirstName, t1.LastName, t2.Sum
FROM Customer as t1 JOIN
     (SELECT CustomerID,Sum(Total) as Sum  FROM Invoice GROUP BY(CustomerID)
     ) t2 
     ON t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID;
```

You can rephrase this as:

```
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, sum(total) as sum
FROM Customer c JOIN
     Invoice i
     ON c.CustomerID = i.CustomerId
GROUP BY c.FirstName, c.LastName;
```

This will work in a view.